# Insert only when occurs a condition

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the next tables:

**Votation**

```
Id: PK
Title: string
Expiration: DateTime
```

**VotationOptions**

```
Id: PK
Option: string
VotationId: FK
```

Users can insert a VotationOption meanwhile Votation.Expiration has not expired.

I can't check the expiration date and after insert an option because in production it could be that the expiration date has not expired and when the option is really inserted in the database, the expiration date has expired.

My code:

```
if (this.context.Votations.First(vot => vot.Id == 1 && vot.Expiration < DateTime.Now == null) return BadRequest();

var option = new VotationOption
{
    Option = "Example",
    VotationId = 1
};

this.context.VotationOptions.Add(option);
this.context.SaveChanges();
```

I want this:

```
this.context.VotationOptions.AddWhere(option, vot => vot.Expiration < DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: Let me get philosophical with you: if they click "vote" one second before the deadline, and it is inserted in the database four seconds after the deadline because there was a five-second lag on your server, didn't they still vote in time?  Just check if it's expired in code, and perform the write if the method fires before the expiration (unless there are user-requirements that say otherwise - if there are, you'll need a database-level constraint to enforce that.)

Comment: You _could_ add an extension method to the type of `VotationOptions` (or a base type) to give you the _syntax_ you want, but there's nothing built in to EF to make the actual code cleaner - you'd essentially just be wrapping your code in an extension method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply using Entity Framework it can't be done. However, you can still use the underlying db context to execute raw SQL so you can use something like:

```
int result = this.context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("INSERT INTO VotationOptions (VotationId, Option) SELECT {your literal values} FROM Votation WHERE {check validity on the votation}");
```

Where `result` would indicate how many rows the database ended up inserting. Keep in mind you'd have to write your validity check such that only 1 result could come back.

However, like @ElementalPete mentions in his comment on your question I'd question the necessity.